# Set extra_float_digits=3 everywhere in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Postgres has a setting called `extra_float_digits`.  It determines how many digits are returned when you select a floating point number in the database.  It defaults to 0 and only applies to the current connection.  If it isn't set to 3, information is lost when you select a value you previously inserted.

Is there a way to set this value so that it will default to 3 in all environments?  I would like it to be set to 3 when I connect via `psql` on the commandline and also when my application connects via a database driver.

Comment: You couldn't just set it in postgresql.conf like everything else?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution #1

Available since PostgreSQL 9.4. Run as an SQL statement when connected as superuser:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET extra_float_digits TO 3;
```

(followed by `select pg_reload_conf();` if it needs take effect immediately)

### Solution #2

Edit the instance-wide `postgresql.conf` configuration file. Locate the existing `extra_float_digits` setting and change it to:

```
extra_float_digits = 3
```

As in the previous solution, a configuration reload is necessary.
Be aware that what's set through `ALTER SYSTEM` takes precedence over what's set in `postgresql.conf`.

### Solution #3

Assign the configuration to specific users (any connection by this user will have this setting by default). Does not require to be superuser if you can connect with that user.

```
ALTER USER username SET extra_float_digits TO 3;
```

### Solution #4

Assign the configuration to specific databases (any connection to this database will have this setting by default). Does not require to be superuser if you're the owner of the database.

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET extra_float_digits TO 3;
```

Comment: Did this work for anybody?